# Website being probed from the Ukraine

Tags: websites

I have a landing page setup for my business located at www.jdmxchange.com and have been getting some strange error logs from ELMAH. I apparently have users (or bots) in the Ukraine probing the hell out of my site. It seems they are trying to figure out what technology I have running under the hood. I get exceptions for invalid paths such as

```
.../wp-login
.../webalizer
.../js/javascriptfile.js
.../user
```

and so forth. At one point I received about 32 errors within a few minutes. This is my first time with a public-facing site and I am not sure which direction to go into reading up on making sure my site is secured. Can anyone point me to a good place to start?

Comment: You mean you didn't perform security testing before you placed your website into the hostile environment we know as the Internet? Hire a security firm to review your website's code and your configuration. Get a HIDS. Block entire countries if you don't plan on doing business with them.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Those sound like some good ideas to delve into.

Comment: A company I currently work for uses incapsula which seems to work well but they are too expensive considering I'm a measly little startup :/

Comment: Well at least look a bit into security management, what you should log, where you should log it, what type of data you are saving (especially if you plan on processing credit card data or personal data).

Comment: Did you just copy stackexchange on your little startup website :P?

Comment: shhhhh. don't tell anyone. I altered it so it would be original ;D. All the other stuff is legit and real though hehe

Comment: Putting a internet faced website without security in mind will put it on the _hacked sites_ category. If you don't have security skills to harden your site, pay someone to do it. Pay it now. Otherwise you will surely be paying someone to fix the mess later.

Comment: Assuming these are ~respectful bots, you might solve this by writing a [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file that excludes (just) them.  This should only take a few minutes to implement while you research/implement more security savvy responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests like the ones you are seeing exist ubiquitously on the Internet. It's called "background radiation" and it's something that everyone with a public service has to deal with.

Don't worry about it. They are random probes looking for holes and if you have properly secured your site against this "background radiation", then you just weather it like everyone else. Assuming, of course, that you have secured your site against this type of threat.

If you are a startup, one of the investments you will have to make is to implement basic security, just like a new brick-and-mortar business would have to invest in locks and a security system. Contact a professional consultant to help you through that process.

Comment: "background radiation" is a good way of thinking of these kind of requests.

Comment: Yes sir I now have cloudflair up and running thanks to you guys! And I blocked Ukraine from the map lol